# What is the role Nodejs in .NET 5 Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly

When you create new .NET 5 Blazor WebAssembly project from Visual Studio 2019 and then run it, Windows Firewall asks for permission for Nodejs.

Why do I need Nodejs? What is its role in .net 5 blazor webassembly project and why does it want to connect to internet?? What happens if I don't allow Nodejs in my firewall?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Answer (score 5):

NodeJS is required to allow debugging client side code from Visual Studio. It plays the role of a debug proxy.
In case of a Blazor code runing in a browser, the real debugger is the Mono debugger which is part of Blazor runtime. To communicate with the debugger, VS uses Node which plays the role of a mapper between the code seen in VS and the one loaded in the browser and communicates with the browser using Chrome DevTools Protocol.
For more details see: [Blazor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug) and this [CaptainSafia's blog post](https://safia.rocks/blog/blazor-wasm-debugging/).