# What is the relationship between Blazor and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, blazor

I am starting some new projects using Blazor.  I use a "hosted" configuration in which I have the client WASM project and also the the server project.  I was using pretty much the latest version of VS 2019 for development.

Today for the first time ever in history I had a VS build simply hang.  Cancelling the build was unresponsive, I had to kill VS from the task manager.  When I googled that up I got a phone book of old posts that had nothing to do with Blazor.  Apparently VS used to do this but it had long since been fixed.

So I decided for good measure to update my VS.  It was behind by maybe a couple of patches.  In doing so the VS Installer wouldn't let the update continue because the process "node" was running.  That was how I discovered I had a couple of Node.exe process running on my machine.  I have never installed or used NodeJS wittingly.  The only reason it could be there is because of these new Blazor projects.

I have to assume the NodeJS process was also the reason my build hung.  I tried googling up this relationship between Blazor and NodeJS to understand why these processes were running on my machine, but all I get is people who are trying to explicitly install NodeJS to use it their projects.  I can't find anything that talks about NodeJS being part of Blazor by default, but there is no other reason for these Node.exe processes to be running on my machine.

Comment: You're assuming that Node is related specifically to Blazor, and not just used as a tool by Visual Studio for various purposes. I wouldn't jump to that conclusion if I were you.

Comment: I just found this.  It is used as a debug proxy for Blazor web assembly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67390460/what-is-the-role-nodejs-in-net-5-blazor-webassembly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the role Nodejs in .NET 5 Blazor WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67390460/what-is-the-role-nodejs-in-net-5-blazor-webassembly)

Answer (score 1):

I found this SO post: [What is the role Nodejs in .NET 5 Blazor WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67390460/what-is-the-role-nodejs-in-net-5-blazor-webassembly)

Apparently it is a debug proxy.  Here is a link directly to the MS documentation.  How neither of these were top results in my initial search I do not know.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio